# Use build in colors in xml?

Tags: java, android

How can I make use of `android.grapics.color` constants?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

This does not work:

```
android:drawable="@android:color/cyan"
```

Comment: Your formatting is correct. You simply aren't using one of the valid colors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

android.R.provides [these colors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html).

If you want to use the [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class, you need some java code :

```
view.setBackgroundColor( Color.CYAN );
```

Comment: I agree, I don't believe there is a color/cyan.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting a color to android:drawable. Are you trying to set a background? Because then you'd use:

```
android:background="@android:color/black"
```

Although in my editor I don't see cyan as an option. If you just cntrl+space in the xml field, you can pick @android:color/ and then pick a color. You can always make your own in the colors.xml file though :)

Comment: Also. android:drawable="@android:color/*" may be perfectly valid... But yeah! Maybe it's because there's no color/cyan in their default xml parameters?